# How can I use HttpContext in public class

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

How can I use HttpContext in public class. I have all method about Cookies in one class without this:

```
        public HttpCookie SetAndGetHttpCookies()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("MyCookieGitApplication");
        CookieHelper cookieHelper = new CookieHelper();

        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = cookieHelper.SetCookie();
        }

        return cookie;
    }
```

Any idea how can I use HttpContext.Request in public class? Maybe someone have different way to get cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried HttpContext.Current?
If you're using ASP.NET this should be a way to access the current context from anywhere in your code. If you're not, the solution is trickier.

I.E.

```
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("MyCookieGitApplication");
```

Comment: It's working but now HttpContext doesnt contain Cookies
HttpContext.Request.Cookies <--

Comment: Happy to help :)
Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your probelm

Comment: I know but i must wait 5 min (probably post must be active for X min). I try it when u solve my problem :). And also I cant give you +1 cuz i haven't 15 point :<